# Why my own "toString()" function doesn't work in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, tostring

I tried in my chrome debug console:

```
>function m(){function toString(){return "abc"}}
undefined
>new m().toString()
"[object Object]"
```

I expect it to print "abc". Why?

Comment: A function used as a constructor should return an object. If it doesn't, the return value is ignored and an object is returned instead.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between local variables and object properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using your own `toString` method (which is a private function inside of `m`), but the one from [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

For your own method, you need to assign your `toString` method to `m`'s prototype, like

```
m.prototype.toString = function () { return 'abc'; };
```

```js
function m() {}
m.prototype.toString = function () { return 'abc'; };

console.log((new m).toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```js
function m() {
  this.toString = function() {
    return "abc";
  }
}

var m1 = new m();
alert(m1.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. You can try this code and check output here http://jsbin.com/luremulano/edit?html,js,console,output

```
  console.log(m('abc'));

  function m(a){
      return a.toString();  
  }
```